# Calculus: show that $h(x)-f(x)\geq 0$

Tags: calculus, functions

Be $h:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, $h(x)=\max\{f(x),g(x)\}$. Show that for any $x$, $h(x)-f(x)\geq0$.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $h(x)-f(x)\geq 0$ is the same as $h(x)\geq f(x)$. (You can see this by subtracting $f(x)$ from both sides.)

Since $h$ is defined as the $\max$ of $f$ and $g$, do you see why it has to be greater than or equal to $f$? What would have to be true if it weren't, at some point?

Comment: The problem I had with the question are the h be defined as the max of f and g. Now I understood, thanks